# I am having two iframes in the html page. Date picker id's are not accepting into two iframes div id's properly

Tags: html, iframe, knockout.js

> I am generating random div id's from ko(Knockout.js) file for the
>   start and end date pickers .Data binding is not happening for the
>   respective date picker id's in html file. So, as we are having two
>   iframes in the html file, random id's are not binding to the html file
>   div id's. Only one div id from the randomly generated div id's are
>   assigning to the start and end date div id's in the html file. I am
>   binding the div id's using the knockout.js.
>
> Note:- Please check the iframe div id's{id's:= target1, target2} in
>   the jsfiddl HTML part.
>
> Please find the below link for the code.
>   http://jsfiddle.net/omrse0yj/3/

```
<div id="target1" style="width:420px; height:900px; overflow:hidden;"></div>
        <br/>
        <br/>
         <div id="target2"></div>

<p><a href="#" class="btn small" data-date-format="mm/dd/yyyy" data-date="" data-bind="attr: {'id': startDatePickerDivId}">
                                                <img src="images/dt-icon.png" alt="Start Date" tabindex="2"/></a>Start Date</p>
                                        <p data-bind="attr: {'id': startDateDivId}">07/07/2015</p>

<p><a href="#" class="btn small" data-date-format="mm/dd/yyyy" data-date="" data-bind="attr: {'id': endDatePickerDivId}">
                                                <img src="images/dt-icon.png" alt="End Date" tabindex="3"/></a> End Date</p>
```

07/10/2015

---

> PS:- Please check the code in the Jsfiddle link:-
>   http://jsfiddle.net/omrse0yj/3/

```
{This is not the exact code for the solution, hope one will get idea after seeing the code in the fiddle}
```

---

Comment: I don't see where you call `ko.applyBindings`. The code itself is mostly jQuery, which is likely to cause problems with knockout. Start with a minimal example that only has the code necessary to illustrate the problem. Preferably code that runs.

Comment: Please find the updated code in above updated jsfiddle link @Roy........"element" inside the ko.applyBindings function is like we are reading each div inside the "element"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated your fiddle so that it runs without error and applies the knockout bindings. The ids of the start and end dates are assigned, and the bindings are applied specifically to the div. I commented out the jQuery code, as it wasn't relevant to the question.

```
var prefix = "test_" + test.randomChars(5);

function WidgetVM() {
    var prefix = "test_" + test.randomChars(5);
    this.graphDivId = ko.observable(prefix + "_graph");
    this.startDateDivId = ko.observable(prefix + "_startDate");
    this.endDateDivId = ko.observable(prefix + "_endDate");
    this.startDatePickerDivId = ko.observable(prefix + "_startDatePicker");
    this.endDatePickerDivId = ko.observable(prefix + "_endDatePicker");
}

ko.applyBindings(new WidgetVM(), $('#target1')[0]); //here element is the div id
```

http://jsfiddle.net/omrse0yj/6/

Comment: Hi @Roy, Thanks for the update. I will get back to you with the solution.